# How do you use order of operations in programming?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, operator-precedence

Is there a good way to use order of operation in programming? How could you write this equation in code for example? x = 2(100 - 50)

Comment: you have to be explicit with each step and operator.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/

Comment: The best way to learn something simple like this is to try it out :)

Comment: Try .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: Please add a little more information to your question indicating what is confusing you or not working for you.

Comment: order of operations is enforced automatically. not sure what you're asking..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be overthinking it :)

```
var x = 2 * (100 - 50);
```

As said in the comments, the best way to learn is often to try it out for yourself!

Comment: I thought that parenthesis might cause an error because... Parameters. :p Yeah I need to experiment new stuffs for myself. Thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking though, PEMDAS applies in cases like this.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Can you give an example of when operators having equal precedence can lead to error?